# Cannot connect to Spark cluster programmatically but spark-shell can?

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, apache-spark

I am running an application and am having trouble connecting to Spark. Here's the relevant code:

```
System.setProperty("spark.akka.frameSize", "200")
System.setProperty("spark.akka.timeout", "100")
System.setProperty("spark.default.parallelism", "288")
var sparkmaster = "spark://1.17.8.5:7098"
var sc = new SparkContext(sparkmaster, "tool", "/opt/spark")
```

The relevant output is:

```
13/08/14 17:15:30 INFO storage.BlockManagerUI: Started BlockManager web UI at ----
13/08/14 17:15:30 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR target/scala-2.9.1/pivot-spark_2.9.1-1.0.jar at http://1.17.8.5:50262/jars/tool_2.9.1-1.0.jar with timestamp 1376500530641
13/08/14 17:15:30 INFO cluster.FairSchedulableBuilder: Create default pool with name:default,schedulingMode:FIFO,minShare:2,weight:1
13/08/14 17:15:30 INFO client.Client$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://1.17.8.5:7098
```

As you can see it does not actually connect to the workers. However, if I just run `spark-shell` in the terminal, I get:

```
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO BlockManagerUI: Started BlockManager web UI at ---
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO Client$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://1.17.8.5:7098
Spark context available as sc.
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20130814172553-0029
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO Client$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20130814172553-0029/0 on worker-20130808012122----42908 with 4 cores
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20130814172553-0029/0 on host --- with 4 cores, 8.0 GB RAM
13/08/14 17:25:53 INFO Client$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20130814172553-0029/1 on worker-20130808012122-----59902 --- with 4 cores
...etc
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Turns out I needed to set an environment variable `$SPARK_HOME` that `spark-shell` seemed to be setting automatically.